# CodeIgniter: index.php shown in plain text

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on a school project in `CodeIgniter`, sharing a `GitHub` repository with the team.

The code is running fine and displaying the webpage as it should at another member's computer.

On my machine however (`Ubuntu 14` and working in `Netbeans IDE`), running the project displays a page with part of the content of the standard `index.php` file in the `CI` root directory in **plain text**, as can be seen in the image below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGyzC.png]

I have `Apache2` and `php5` installed, as well as `libapache2-mod-php5`.
Running another project with `CodeIgniter` and using functions like `phpinfo()` works fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: whats that first bit `='))` that looks a bit off, no? missing `'` perhaps.

Comment: Your image shows you accessing the page over localhost and since another member's computer could not access over localhost you may have an issue with your VirtualServer configs.  Where one is either reading from a different source directory or one is executing PHP files while the other is returning them as text.  I'd start there and compare the configs.

Comment: There's a part comming before that, that seems to be executed:
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
 case 'development':
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 break;

 case 'testing':
 case 'production':
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the reply. The configs seem to be fine, pointing to the right directory, which is accessible via localhost. I only changed the database password and username to my own.

Comment: Let's see the entire contents of index.php

Comment: Daniel, the file showing up here is (part of) the file that can be found here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php and is a standard CI file.
The page that's supposed to show up is pointed to correctly by our controller, which is configured as the default controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on different operating systems, you may need to [change your line ending configurations](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) on your computer: `git config --global core.autocrlf input`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Briana. Unfortunately that's not it, since we're both working on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a permissions problem... Solved it by running 'chmod -R 777' on my projects directory.

Thanks for the help guys!